# Change button styles for ngx-ui-switch angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm using [ngx-ui-switch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-ui-switch) for switch buttons. I wanted to give custom size for the buttons.

This plugin generates some css which is not found in my project folder.

If i try to change it manually like `.switch-small[_ngcontent-c20] {size:40px}` is not working. Please help

**Original HTML**

```html
<ui-switch [checked]="staticProposalFlag" (change)="onProposalChange($event)" size="small" class="float-left" switchColor="#D9D9D9" color="#1D79D1"></ui-switch>
```

Generated HTML

```html
<ui-switch _ngcontent-c13="" class="float-left" color="#1D79D1" size="small" switchcolor="#D9D9D9" _nghost-c20="" ng-reflect-size="small" ng-reflect-color="#1D79D1" ng-reflect-switch-color="#D9D9D9" ng-reflect-checked="true">
  <span _ngcontent-c20="" class="switch checked switch-small" style="background-color: rgb(29, 121, 209); border-color: rgb(223, 223, 223);">
    <small _ngcontent-c20="" style="background: rgb(217, 217, 217);">
    </small>
    </span>
</ui-switch>
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to change the CSS of UI switch, use `::ng-deep` and `!important` together. Only that works in my case.

Example:

```
::ng-deep .switch-small.checked small {
    left: 16px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the CSS of the component itself with the `ng` identifier added before, so try to add a real class instead of `float left` which is a style rule. Create a class `customSwitch` (replace `float:left`). And in your CSS add
`.switchCustom { float:left; width: 100px }` + remove `size=small` it looks like a parameter that could be in conflict when trying to set the width.

Comment: i did, but still i'm not able to change the size of the buttons `.switch-small[_ngcontent-c20] {
    width: 33px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}`

Comment: Remove [_ngcontent] in your CSS it is a generated value

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the UI switch creating a black border / outline after being clicked, i can confirm that krithika's solution above works:

```
::ng-deep button.switch {
  outline: none !important;
}
```